# Is it possible to use properties on module variables instead of instance attributes?

Tags: python, module, properties

What I wish:

```
# main.py
import config
config.test = True  # prints 'config: test is set to True'
print(config.test)  # True
```

What I tried:

```
# config.py
_test = False

@property
def test():
    return _test

@test.setter
def test(new_value):
    global _test
    _test = new_value
    logger.info(f'config: test is set to {new_value}')
```

Avoiding using a conventional method like config.set_test(new_value) would be neat.
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Make it a class

```
class Config:
    @property
    def test(self):
        return self._test

    @test.setter
    def test(self, value):
        self._test = value

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._test = None
```

However, in a way this makes no sense, and the reason is because you have a getter AND setter so, really you are just going the long way around to set the var. You could just convert `self._test` to `self.test` and remove the getter/setter for the same results.

The below version only has a getter which implies you have a var that you want to modify internally, but be "read-only" publically.

```
class Config:
    @property
    def test(self):
        return self._test

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._test = None
```

IMO, it only makes sense to have a setter if the guts of the setter are doing something non-trivial. For instance, if you were using `tkinter` and you wanted to convert the options to properties, it might make sense to have a setter because what you are getting and setting is actually TCL calls. In other words, it's not just some alias for a private var.

Example:

```
#mixin to convert root attributes and options to properties
class Root_mi:         
    @property
    def alpha(self) -> float:
        return self.tk.call('wm', 'attributes', self._w, '-alpha')
        
    @alpha.setter
    def alpha(self, f:float) -> None:
        self.tk.call('wm', 'attributes', self._w, '-alpha', f)
       
    @property
    def alwaysontop(self) -> bool:
        return self.tk.call('wm', 'attributes', self._w, '-topmost')
        
    @alwaysontop.setter
    def alwaysontop(self, b:bool) -> None:
        self.tk.call('wm', 'attributes', self._w, '-topmost', b)
        
#more...
```

Comment: i would like to do
config.test = True or False
and that this also logs that event